# Is is possible to cancel a bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

Is it possible to cancel a bounty if I found the answer to my question?

Comment: Do you mean you want to cancel your bounty or how to award it to someone who answered your question?

Comment: I originally meant how to cancel a bounty if still anybody hasn't answered the question and in the meantime i found a answer to my question on my own. But acutal the question is done, because someone answered the question and i will going to award him the bounty i started. Just in general, can a bounty be cancel if anybody hasn't answered so far?

Comment: If the answer you found is very different from any existing answer on that question, you should also post an answer yourself.

Comment: You're allowed to answer your own question though you won't get your bounty back!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Details on the bounty system are here: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

At the bottom of the answer you'll see that you can't cancel a bounty. I assume you're referring to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16688/how-can-i-add-specific-folders-to-places-in-mintmenu). ændrük's answer will at least get the automatic bounty for half of the rep at the end of the period.

Personally I would just give him the full bounty for the effort (since once you spend the 50 it's gone for good). It's a good answer with nice screenshots so the next person will get a easy to use answer.

Comment: thanks for the answer, yes that was my plan. I stated this in the comment to my question above, that i definitly will give him the award. Did it some minutes ago, because i had to wait the system waiting time for transfer rewards.